# How can I 'close' poll in Django

Tags: python, django

Say I have this class for `Poll` objects in my `models.py`:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

    # Opened by default.
    is_opened = True

    def close_poll(self):
        self.is_opened = False
         # Don't know how to implement this...

    def open_poll(self):
        self.is_opened = True
        # Don't know how to implement this...

    def pub_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date < now
    pub_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    pub_recently.boolean = True
    pub_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'
```

When I use the `close_poll` function in `python manage.py shell` it sets `is_opened` variable to `False`.  But it stays set to `False` only for this one shell session.

So how can I implement this cleverly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this right, you should do like this:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

So, while doing query do like this:

```
Poll.objects.filter(is_active=True)
```

which will only get your active polls.